# Decrease product total sales count from cancelled WooCommerce Orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I'm displaying the total sales using `get_total_sales()` WC_Product method, in a product table of my WooCommerce store.

However this number doesn't get updated after an user cancel its order, it keeps adding sales.

Anybody can show me how to change this get_total_sales formula, to be able to remove the canceled ordered numbers in the total sales?

Comment: WOW, that worked! 
Cant thank you enough, just donated. 
Woocommerce should have that option to keep real numbers in sales. 
If i wanted to make this available for the "On Hold" status, it should be just add that status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, the related product total sales doesn't decrease when a paid order (from processing or complete status) is cancelled in WooCommerce 3+…

For info, **Paid** orders includes "processing" and "completed" order statuses.

The following will decrease the product total sales when a paid order is cancelled by a Customer, a Shop manager or an Administrator:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'update_product_total_sales_on_cancelled_orders', 10, 4 );
function update_product_total_sales_on_cancelled_orders( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $order ){
    if ( in_array( $old_status, array('processing', 'completed') ) && 'cancelled' === $new_status
    && ! $order->get_meta('_order_is_canceled') ) {

        // Loop through order items
        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
            // Get the WC_product object (and for product variation, the parent variable product)
            $product = $item->get_variation_id() > 0 ? wc_get_product( $item->get_product_id() ) : $item->get_product();

            $total_sales   = (int) $product->get_total_sales(); // get product total sales
            $item_quantity = (int) $item->get_quantity(); // Get order item quantity

            $product->set_total_sales( $total_sales - $item_quantity ); // Decrease product total sales
            $product->save(); // save to database
        }
        $order->update_meta_data('_order_is_canceled', '1'); // Flag the order as been cancelled to avoid repetitions
        $order->save(); // save to database
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.